# DMS doesn't understand schema changes from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-schema, aws-dms

I am trying to load data into S3 from mongoDB using AWS Data Migration Service(DMS).

My collections have fields with different schemas, in some of the documents this field can be integer and others it can be double.

When I load the CSV in my Glue Job and create a table for this collection the table gets created with field's data type as integer, and has null values in those documents wherever this field's data type is double.

I'm using the table mode to write CSV files from DMS.

Comment: can you do printSchema immediately after reading into dynamic frame ? If you have choice type then you should do https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find solution?